# Creating docker image that executes commands in python virtualenv

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker, virtualenv

I have the following problem ...

I want to create a docker image on which a python virtual environment is created. Then I want to be able to do the following two things:

- Run `docker run -it <image>` to start an interactive shell in this
  virtual environment.
- Run `docker run <image> <command>` (such as python --version) that is
  executed in said virtual environment

I tried many things but it seems I don't get anywhere. My Dockerfile looks currently like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y python3 python-pip
RUN pip install virtualenv
RUN virtualenv -p python3.5 /venvs/myenv3.5
RUN . /venvs/myenv3.5/bin/activate && pip install numpy
```

I tried messing around with ENTRYPOINT and CMD but I don't get anywhere. By adding the following line: `CMD . /venvs/myenv3.5/bin/activate; /bin/bash;` I was able to start an interactive bash in the environment, but running docker run  python --version shows that commands like that are not executed in said environment.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: have a look at https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2015/04/docker-and-virtualenv-a-clean-way-to-locally-install-python-dependencies-with-pip-in-docker/

Comment: This is how I did it now (unfortunately not very elegant xD):
`ENV PATH <path to venv bin>:$PATH`

If anybody has a cleaner solution, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/venvs/myenv3.5/bin/python` executable instead of the main `python`. This will execute `python` within that virtual environment. You can do this by doing `ENV PATH /venvs/myenv3.5/bin:$PATH` as you mentioned in the comments or by using an entrypoint in `Dockerfile`:

```
ENTRYPOINT /venvs/myenv3.5/bin/python
```

Now when you run your image, your virtualenv `python` will be executed by default:

```
$ docker run -it <image> --version
Python 3.5.2
```

If you need to get a shell on this image, you can overwrite the entrypont:

```
$ docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash <image>
/ #
```

You can also use `/venvs/myenv3.5/bin/pip` to install things into the virtualenv:

```
RUN /venvs/myenv3.5/bin/pip install numpy
```